# How do we change class name from script

Tags: javascript, html, class

Hello is there any way to edit html tag class name from script?
For example:

html:

```
<div id="ThisIsId" class= "ThisIsName"> ... </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("ThisIsId").changeClassName("thisIsNewClassName") 
</script>
```

Comment: `.className = "thisIsNewClassName"` is one way, `.setAttribute('class',"thisIsNewClassName")` is method 2

Comment: is it a property or function

Comment: one of each, the first is a property, the second is a method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
document.getElementById("ThisIsId").classList.remove("ThisIsName").add("thisIsNewClassName") 
</script>
```

Comment: What about .className = "thisIsNewClassName"

Comment: This will remove all other classes of the element

Comment: like <div class="hi" class = "anotherClass"> that will remove all of the classes?

Comment: See, that is a basic thing, if you will have another class, then it will remove them. Also, one element cannot have multiple attributes with same name. And it's better to check first rather than directly asking here.